# What does "cx_" prefix stand for in package names?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I see `cx_` prefix in package names like [cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). What does it mean? If it's an acronym, how to decrypt it?

Comment: I would guess it's a wrapper around a C++ interface... but I really don't know.

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing :) Based on http://cx-oracletools.sourceforge.net/cx_OracleTools.html I think "cx" may mean "cross" as in "cross platform" but I have no idea. FWIW The phrase "cross platform" is also mentioned in the cx_Freeze docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd better ask the author about that)
However, I have a strong theory that it's derived from "Computronix" - the name of the company Anthony [worked for](http://starship.python.net/crew/atuining/):

> These are a bunch of projects that I have worked on at Computronix and which they have agreed to release as open source. See Computronix Open Source Utilities.

Comment: Yes, it stands for Computronix

Answer (score 0):

CX_ stands for "customer experience".

e.g The "Oracle CX cloud" is the "Oracle Customer Experience Cloud"

http://searchcrm.techtarget.com/definition/Oracle-Customer-Experience-Cloud-Oracle-CX-Cloud